# How to print list to specific cell(s) (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to print the following based on user inputs (say apple=2, orange=3):

```
(Cell C10): Apple 1    
(Cell C11): Apple 2
(Cell C12): Orange 1
(Cell C13): Orange 2
(Cell C14): Orange 3
(Cell C15): Hello world 1
(Cell C16): Hello world 2
```

However when I run the script, Apple 1 outputs to cell C2. What do I need to modify in order to print Apple 1 to cell C10?

My code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim apple As Integer, orange As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, lRow As Long, sentence1 As Long, sentence2 As Long

lRow = Cells(10, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
apple = InputBox("Please enter number of apples")
orange = InputBox("Please enter number of oranges")
sentence1 = 1
sentence2 = 1   

    For i = 1 To apple
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Apple " & i
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next i

    For j = 1 To orange
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Orange " & j
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next j
    
    For k = 1 To sentence1
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Hello world 1"
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next k
    
    For l = 1 To sentence2
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Hello world 2"
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next l
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `End(xlUp)` you're doing the same thing as Ctrl+Up, so you're changing the row. If you want row 10, then just do `lRow=10`

Comment: wow thank you so much, that worked. I can't believe how simple it was. I guess where I put "lRow=lRow+1" it already moves the row down.